# Equation for an 's' curve rotated counter clockwise 90 degrees

Tags: graphing-functions

What is the equation for a parabola where if $x$ is positive then $y$ is negative and if $x$ is negative $y$ is positive?

Comment: I infer from your conditions that (0,0) is on the (continuous) curve. You are not dealing with a parabola, but an odd order curve.

Comment: (0,0) is on the continuous curve.  Do you know an equation for a curve like this would be?

Comment: Could you give a concrete example of such a curve and what you've tried with it? That would make helping you much easier.

Comment: Think of the curve $y$ = $x$^2 but when $x$ is positive $y$ is negative and vice versa.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, then I'm pretty sure you're looking for $\frac{-x^3}{|x|}$ [Here's a picture of the graph!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jcs2i.png) You might also be looking for -x^3

Comment: Do you have an equation for the S curve when it is not rotated?

Comment: @Sejr If a question is unclear, please do not answer it.  Instead, please use the comments to seek clarification from the asker.

Comment: What is unclear about this question? And why was the answer deleted? The answer answered my question.